# Explain: "Compatible with all the connectives in $\mathcal{L}$"

Tags: logic

In **A Survey of Abstract Algebraic Logic** the authors introduce implicative logics.  This is the definition that's given:

"These are the logics $S$ having a binary connective $\to$ satisfying the conditions$\phi, \phi\to \psi \vdash_S \psi$ and $\phi\vdash_S \psi\to \phi$  and such that, for each theory $\Sigma$, the relation $\leq_\Sigma$ (defined by:  $\phi\leq_\Sigma \psi$ iff $\Sigma\vdash \phi\to \psi$) is a quasi-order (reflexive and transitive) compatible with all connectives in $\mathcal{L}$."

Here $\mathcal{L}$ is the language studied.

This definition is supposed to generalize usual logics such as classical logic, where you can form the quotient of the formula algebra by the relation $\Sigma\vdash \phi \leftrightarrow \psi$, thus obtaining the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra associated with $\Sigma$.  But in this specific case, the definition doesn't work, since $\leq_\Sigma$ is not, in general compatible with $\neg$ or even to be more general, compatible with $\to$ ($\Sigma \vdash \phi\to \psi$ does not, in general, imply $\Sigma \vdash (\phi \to f)\to (\psi \to f)$ )

So there's probably something I don't understand in the definition or in the point of the definition. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA : yes but that's compatibility of the equivalence relation, not compatibility of the preorder

Comment: The ref in Font&Pigozzi's paper (page 23) is to "Rasiowa's well-known 1974 monograph", i.e. Helena Rasiowa, [An Algebraic Approach to Non-Classical Logics](https://books.google.it/books?id=qa-EAAAAIAAJ). My previous sugegstions was "inspired" by page 183 of Rasiowa's book: $|| \alpha \to \beta || = || \alpha || \to || \beta ||$ and e.g. $\lnot || \alpha || = || \lnot \alpha ||$.

Comment: Maybe you can try asking directly to the authors: font@mat.ub.es or dpigozzi@iastate.edu.